# What is a better approach to filter these two lists into one?

Tags: python, loops

### Background

I have two lists, the first is `items` which contains around 250 tuples, each tuple contains 3 elements

```
(path_to_a_file, size_in_bytes, modified_time)
```

The second list, `result` contains anywhere up to 250 elements, which is the result of a database query which looks up rows based on the paths that are in the `items` list. The number of elements in `result` depends if those files are in the database already.

each element in result is an row object returned from SQLAlchemy query with attributes for the row values, (`path`, `mtime` and `hash` are the ones I'm interested in here)

What I'm trying and do is filter out all the elements in `items` that are in `results` that have the same mtime (and keep track of the number, and total size filtered) and make a new list with items either with a different mtime or that dont exist in `result`. items with different mtimes need to be stored `(path,size,mtime_from_result,hash_from_result)` and items which weren't in the database `(path,size,mtime,None)`.

I hope I'm not making this too localised but I felt I needed to explain what I'm trying to accomplish to ask the question.

### Problem

I want to try and make this loop as fast as possible but the most important part is making it work as expected.

Is it safe to remove items from the lists as I iterate over them? I noticed iterating forwards has a weird outcome but iterating backwards seems to be ok. Is there a better approach?

I'm removing items that I've matched up (`i.path == j[0]`) because I know the relationship is 1 to 1 and its not going to match again so by reducing the lists I can iterate over it faster in the next iteration, and more importantly I get left with all the unmatched items.

I can't help feel there's a much nicer solution that I'm overlooking, perhaps with list comprehension or generators perhaps.

```
send_items=[]
for i in result[::-1]:
    for j in items[::-1]:
        if i.path==j[0]:
            result.remove(i) #I think this remove is possibly pointless?
            items.remove(j)
            if i.mtime==j[2]:
                self.num_skipped+=1
                self.size_skipped+=j[1]
            else:
                send_items.append((j[0],j[1],i.mtime,i.hash))
            break
send_items.extend(((j[0],j[1],j[2],None) for j in items))
```

Comment: Instead of removing items, copy the ones you want to keep to a new list. If you want to keep track of mtimes already seen, put them in a set.

Comment: What is the structure of `result` ?

Comment: Instead of searching in a list linearly, I guess it comes out less costly to build up proper data structures like dicts or sets before doing your work.

Comment: If items were a dict keyed on pathname this would become much simpler. Is there a reason it can't be?  Can the same pathname show up multiple times?

Comment: No, the pathname will be unique

Comment: `result[::-1]` creates a copy of `result` (albeit reversed, you can get a proper copy by calling `result[::]`), so calling `remove()` on it is pointless. It would be even if it weren't a copy: you have to iterate over all of it anyways. It is less pointless on `items`, but calling `remove()` on `items` actually reduces the efficiency of this algorithm from O(N^2) to O(N^3), because `remove()` takes O(N) time. A solution like mine is O(N) on the other hand.

Comment: I realise now I should have unpacked items into variables to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do this as:

```
def get_send_items(items, results):
    send_items = []
    results_dict = {i.path:i for i in results}
    for p, s, m in items:
        result = results_dict.get(p)
        if result is None:
            send_items.append((p, s, m, None))
        elif result.mtime != m:
            send_items.append((p, s, result.mtime, result.hash))
    return send_items
```

Here is my analysis of your solution (Assuming both `result` and `items` are of length N):

- `result[::-1]` creates a copy of `result` so calling `result.remove(i)` doesn't affect the iteration, nor would it have anyways. You only loop over `result` once, so removing elements is a bit pointless. It only creates extra work.
- You could have called `result[::]` to create a copy of `result`.
- Calling `items.remove(j)` actually **reduces** efficiency. `remove()` takes O(N) time. So calling it reduces the algorithm's efficiency to O(N^3) from O(N^2).
- By using O(N) extra memory (as in my solution) you can reduce the run time to O(N), if you use a dictionary or a set that has O(1) look ups.

Comment: Ah, I overlooked completely that slicing creates a new list- well I overlooked that setting the step is still slicing :) so I wasn't removing from the list I was iterating over at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am assuming that the file path identifies a file - that they are unique.

We create a dictionary of the results, so we can easily check for membership, and check the values associated with it.

```
dict_results = {file: (size, modified_time) for file, size, modified_time in results}
```

We can then use a list comprehension to filter out the elements you don't want:

```
[(file, size, modified_time) for file, size, modified_time in items if (file not in dict_results) or (not dict_results[file][1] == modified_time)]
```

E.g:

```
>>> results = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 3)]
>>> items = [(1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
>>> dict_results = {file: (size, modified_time) for file, size, modified_time in results}
>>> [(file, size, modified_time) for file, size, modified_time in items if (file not in dict_results) or (not dict_results[file][1] == modified_time)]
[(2, 2, 2), (3, 3, 3)]
```

Comment: This is a good start thanks, I like this idea- I'll have to compare speeds. The only part missing is including in the mtime and hash from the database record if there was one, or the mtime from items and None if not.

Answer (score 0):

How about inserting the results into a set as Marcin suggests, and using a list comprehension to filter the items:

```
mtimes_set = set(result[2] for result in results)
send_items = (item for item in items if item[2] not in mtimes_set)
```

---

Misunderstood the path part. This can still be done (although a bit ugly around the last set of brackets):

```
path_dict = dict((result[0], result) for result in results)
send_items = (item for item in items if item[0] in path_dict and path_dict[item[0]][2] != item[2])
```

Here I am creating a dictionary of seen paths, then a generator returning those which have a path in the dict, and that have the different mtime. It could easily be changes to return the path_dict result item instead here instead of item now.

Comment: items is list of tuples of three; send_items shall be list of tuples of four (IIRC).

Comment: I need to check the mtime only for the matching file (where the paths match), the other mtimes are for other unrelated files

Comment: `where` is not a valid keyword in Python. You are looking for `if`. Other than that, this appears to be a nice answer.

Comment: Doh. I missed that. And I am now aware that this may not have answered the question as he wanted it. I think actually I need to store a dict of paths: tuples, then look up the path, and return those where the mtime is different...

Comment: And there is a 2 line answer I am mostly happy with - although I may use something to make the square bracket mess on the second line pleasanter...

Answer (score 0):

First stab:

```
items_dict = dict( (el[0], el[1:]) for el in items )
new = []
modified = []
other = []
for res in result:
    put_to = None
    item = items_dict.get(res.path, (None, None))
    if item is (None, None):
        put_to = new
    elif res.mtime != item[1]:
        put_to = modified
    else:
        put_to = other
    put_to.append( (res.path, item) )
```

Comment: The left over items will be lost here I think, result is a subset of items so new will always be empty. I guess it will work if I swapped items_dict for result_dict and looped over items.

Comment: @GP89 Alternatively - if you're using a SQL database, create a view of `results` that has the same columns as `items` - then do a `FULL  OUTER JOIN` on path. And analyse from there?

Comment: Then when you got that - it'd be a case of `select * from join_view_or_whatever case when item.mtime <> result.time then ... when item.path is null then ... when result.path is null then... end`

Comment: Interesting, items isn't another database table though- would that still be possible? It's the resulting files from scanning the file system.

Comment: Can work both ways I guess - you either upload the items into a temp table and have the server do the join, or as you mention you're pulling the results from the DB, create a temporary sqlite3 in-memory database with a results and items table, have that do the join, then process how you want with Python. (If that makes sense)

Comment: Saves a lot of looping etc... and most people will read the SQL statement for its intent and purpose, plus if things change, the SQL will be more adaptable later on

Comment: Ah thanks. I think I'd rather keep the filtering in python but it is a cool solution and not one I thought about. Maybe this would work well if I was doing the whole table at once but I need to show some progress as I'm doing this filtering, and pulling records out 250 at a time improved the speed considerably from getting them one at a time.

Comment: I don't understand - you wouldn't retrieve them one at a time... you'd take 250 - so for the main db, you'd do "select * from results limit 250" (or whatever), put that in an in memory DB, get than to join with items, then still filter in Python

Comment: Sorry - keep forgetting to @GP89

Comment: I don't think you need to add @ for me to get a notification, i think it will notify me because I've commented previously. Ah, I mean that's the reason I'm currently dealing with groups of 250, and not doing it 1 by 1, and any larger and the jumps in progress would be too great, and also SQLAlchemy throws an exception if I do more than 500 or so at a time. I guess your solution still applies for groups of 250. I can't imagine it'd be quicker though. I might test it out and compare the results

Comment: @GP89 ahh - you didn't mention SQLAlchemy in your OP - querying a database and having an ORM are separate matters :)